# "no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules" for a path that has never been a submodule

Tags: git

> fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'path/name'

When running this command

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git ls-remote origin && git pull origin master --ff-only || true'
```

How to remove any refs to this?

It has never been a submodule. I just cloned it into the repo but deleted it again

Just want to delete all refs to this and get rid of the error?

Comment: In the directory `path/name` is there still a `.git` directory present? Git is probably detecting that (it thinks) you wanted to add a submodule.

Comment: @CoryKramer no the entire root dir of the cloned repo is deleted

Comment: Which command prints this? Show `git status -uall` and `tree -a`.

Comment: @user3840170 have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Backup your repository first (before tweaking its content).

Then start by checking the `.gitmodules` file located at the root of your repository, and check for any references to the path `path/name`.
If there are any, remove the corresponding submodule entry.

```ini
[submodule "path/name"]
    path = path/name
    url = https://example.com/repo.git
```

Check also the `.git/config` file located at the root of your repository, and check for any references to the path `path/name`.
If there are any, remove the corresponding submodule entry.

```ini
[submodule "path/name"]
    url = https://example.com/repo.git
```

Make sure to remove any cached data related to the submodule, if any:

```bash
git rm --cached path/name
```

Finally, check for dangling submodule entries:

```bash
git ls-files --stage | grep path/name
```

If any entries are found, you can remove them using the `git rm` command.

Commit the changes to your repository, and try again the original command again to verify that the error no longer occurs:

```bash
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git ls-remote origin && git pull origin master --ff-only || true'
```

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of that error, first of all open `.gitmodules` file in the root of your repository, and locate the section that contains the reference to the submodule you wana to remove, and delete it, including the lines specifying the path and URL and save the file!
now you need to remove the submodule's entry from the `Git` index and clear any cached information and finally commit the changes to complete the removal of the submodule references!

let me show you how:

```
git rm --cached your_path/name
rm -rf .git/modules/your_path/name
git commit -m "Remove submodule reference: your_path/name"
```

P.S `your_path/name` = the path and name of the submodule you want to remove